# How does Generic work if generic is Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I tried to make abstract class for testing because I found weird problem for using generics

```
abstract class Test<T> {
    open fun hello(vararg data: T) {
        print("Default function")
    }
}
```

This very simple abstract class has one opened method with **vararg** keyword. Problem can be reproduced by making another class which extends *Test* class.

```
class Hello : Test<Int>() {
    //Problem 1
    override fun hello(vararg data: Int) {
        super.hello(*data) //Problem 2
        println("Override function")
    }
}
```

About first problem, Kotlin says method doesn't override anything even though this method surely overrides something. Weirdly, this error happens randomly, so I can't tell exact way to reproduce this bug

[image: Kotlin can't recognize codes]

This error got removed when I add some codes (like really simple code such as `println()`, etc), but when you compile, it causes same error again.

About second problem, `super.hello(*data)` causes problem because this requires `Array<out Int>`, but found parameter is `IntArray`. I think Kotlin is considering `IntArray` and `Array<*>` as different class, but it shouldn't act like this...

[image]

I'm using Kotlin 1.4.10 which seems the latest version according to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/releases.html) site.

I'm posting this to check if these 2 problems are bug or if I did something incorrectly because when I change generic to `String`, all problems get removed.
Are there any mistakes I made in these sample codes above?

Comment: Seems like the overriden method look like `int... data` while the interface one `Integer... data` on the JVM, an interesting question!

Comment: One workaround might be if you could make the parameter nullable — `Int?` instead of `Int` — which should force it to use a generic `Array`.  Ugly, of course, but there doesn't seem to be a neat solution. (One more ugly corner case resulting from the conflicting decisions made in the JVM about arrays and generics…)

Comment: The use of `vararg` seems to be key. Just changing it to `hello(data: Int)` works fine. Looks like you found a limitation/bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9495

As a workaround, you can use the boxed `java.lang.Integer`.

```kotlin
class Hello : Test<Integer>() {
    override fun hello(vararg data: Integer) {
        super.hello(*data)
        println("Override function")
    }
}
```

Comment: Created: 5 years ago. State: To be discussed. Looks like resolving this is not a high priority for the Kotlin team.

Comment: It's funny that if we use `Integer`, IDEA warns us not to use `Integer` while we can't use `Int`. I hope Kotlin team can fix this problem in near future because I think `Int` will be used quite frequently as generic among users. I will accept this answer as solution since it turns out that this problem can't be solved properly, and it's known issues for... 5 years